# OneNote body is not sent when using non-multipart REST

Tags: rest, onenote

I'm having some issues when I try to create a note using OneNote REST API. 
This happens in my application and also when I try to use for testing purpose the apigee tool: https://apigee.com/onenote/embed/console/onenote

After some tests, i've tested the example available on OneNote documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575438(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection3

On apigee, I have the following parameters:
Method: POST
Header: Content-Type: text/html and the corresponding authorization token.
Request Body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>One Simple Note</title>
        <meta name="created" content="2013-06-11T12:45:00.000-8:00"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a simple non-multi-part HTML page.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The note is sent successfully and I receive 201.
When I check my OneNote page, the note is created, but the body of the note is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we had a bug in our system that caused messages under 16kb to be ignored. We just fixed it, so you shouldn't have any problems now!